# Programmatically get all database column types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a Rails gem for which I might need to know the currently available column types. So say for Postgres, I am looking for something like: `ActiveRecord::Base.available_column_types`. I looked through the source with no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find an `ActiveRecord` method to get what you want. But I can show you two ways you can achieve this:

With any path you need to create an initializer and Monkey Patch `ActiveRecord`. For example: `/config/initializers/active_record_extensions.rb`. Then, the options:

**OPTION 1**: get data types based on your models

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.available_column_types
    types = []
    ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.collect{ |type| type.name }.each do |model_name|
      types += eval("#{model_name}.columns.map(&:type)")
    end
    types.uniq
  end
end
```

Then you can do `rails console` on your terminal and write:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.available_column_types
=> [:integer, :string, :text, :datetime, :boolean, :date, :hstore]
irb(main):002:0> ActiveRecord::Base.available_column_types
=> [:integer, :string, :text, :datetime, :boolean, :date, :hstore]
irb(main):003:0>
```

**OPTION 2**: get all posible data types based on you db adapter

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter)
    types = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from pg_type;")
    return types.inject([]) { |result, record| result << record["typname"] }
    # Too much info on pg_type table, you can get whatever you need.
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter)
    # I don't know, it's just an example. Yo can add all adapters you want
    return
  end

  # maybe raise an Exception with NO ADAPTER! message
end
```

end

Once again, on your console, you can do `ActiveRecord::Base.available_column_types` to see the result.

Note: you need to adapt this in order to make it work with your gem.

Comment: Excellent. I actually ended up doing something like option 1 (without the eval). Thank you!